# Is there a way to check if a view is using the correct casing for column and table names?

Tags: sql-server, collation

By default, SQL Server is case insensitive.  If you have a table called 'Test', it's possible to load data from it with a query such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM teST
```

However, this query will fail if the database/server's collation is case sensitive.

We have an application which installs various views and other SQL objects to the user's SQL Server database.  Many of those views currently do not work in case sensitive databases since they use incorrect casing for certain columns and table names.  We're looking into updating our queries to use the correct casing, but this is proving to be tedious to do within a fresh case sensitive database due to dependencies between our SQL objects.

One thing which could speed this up is if given a case insensitive database which already has all of our SQL objects, we can easily detect views which use incorrect casing.  Is there anyway to do this?  For example, when running the above query, is there anyway we could specify an option or query hint or anything to get an error that the table 'teST' is invalid or has incorrect casing?

Comment: A couple of comments: 1) avoid case sensitive collations on database level unless you really want to experience new levels of pain 2) you can create a database on your test server with case sensitive collation and then try to create views there one by one, if view creation fails, it means you have to fix it

Comment: If you use a Visual Studio SQL Server database project, the build will generate warnings if referenced names differ by case, even in a case insensitive collation.

Comment: I love using case sensitive in dev and staging environments because these views could never get to production that way. You can look at `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` for table names (and compare them to `sys.tables`/`sys.schemas` using a binary collation), and `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set()` for column names, however if you have `SELECT x = t1.a, y = t2.a FROM dbo.t1 JOIN dbo.t2` it's going to be really hard to use that output to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks siggemannen.  I figured we'd likely have to do something like your suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

you can try sys.sql_dependencies

```
select * 
from sys.views
where object_id not in (select object_id from sys.sql_dependencies)
```